# iOS PhoneGap. Prevent iFrame from caching

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, html, cordova

In a PhoneGap App for iPad I have an iFrame which shows data stored in an online database. In a further step, I download this data via JSON and edit it in the app. When I'm done, I return to the iFrame but it still shows the old data. With JSON i get the new correct data.

...In short, the app caches the content of the iFrame

I tried everything to prevent caching including the usual meta-tag stuff in the page

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
```

and calling the page with a timestamp as get-parameter. I even tried to re-render the whole iFrame via JavaScript but it still does not work.

```
function loadFrame() {
var cid = localStorage.getItem("cid");  
var ts = new Date().getTime();
var url = pageURL+"?c=" +cid + "&timestamp=" + ts;

localStorage.removeItem("cid");

ifid = "iframe_" + ts;  

$("#iframe_wrap").html('<iframe name="iframe" id="'+ifid+'" src="'+url+'" class="fullscreen"></iframe>');
$("#"+ifid).hide();
$("#"+ifid).one("load",onLoad);

console.log("URL in iFrame '#"+ifid+"': "+url);
}
```

Only when I restart the app, I get the new page

Is there any way to resolve this problem?

Comment: How do you `return to the iFrame`? Maybe you should append a timestamp to the page containing the iFrame? Or is this a single-page app?

Comment: Its a single-page-app, but my views get loaded via AJAX in a container. Unfortunately your tip also didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved the problem but it's only partially iOS' fault!

What I forgot to mention is that the page in the iFrame also displays data from AJAX requests. In iOS 6, AJAX requests get cached, even if you say "cache: false" (We use jQuery).

So to get the latest data, you have to add a random but everytime unique value as parameter (I use the timestamp). I adviced my colleague (he made that data-displaying-page) to add this parameter and now it works.

When I load data directly in the app, I already did this trick, he not :)